# Google analytics - Find what time users entered the site from traffic source

Tags: google-analytics

The title says it all, I'm trying to find what time each visit came from a particular traffic source. EG if I wanted to find all the times that users visited from Google (Organic) - Can I do this i GA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.

1. Create a custom Advanced Segment that only shows traffic from Google
2. Go to Visitors > Visitor Trending > Visits
3. Click on the Clock icon in the 'Graph by' section to show Visits by Hour

An easy way to test this without creating a custom segment is to use the default segment 'Non-paid search traffic'.  This should show a similar pattern to Google organic search traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Google Analytics will allow you to drill down beyond a particular day, though it will let you expand to weekly or monthly views. To get that kind of data, you'd need to use a different services, possibly a real-time analytics script.